# Not needing brackets when not passing any arguments

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I am creating a function with this line:

```
window.Spark = window.$ = function(selector, context) { ... };
```

But I am having a problem (obviously), if I call a function like this `$('p').content('Hi!');` then everything works great because I am treating $ like a function. However, when I run a function like this `$.ajax('get', 'example.txt');` I get this error `$.ajax is not a function`. This is because I am not including the brackets. Does anyone know a way around this? I saw in the jQuery source that they have a function within a function. Is this the sort of thing I need?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume by brackets you mean parentheses.

In jQuery, `$` is a function with properties.
You can replicate this type of behavior simply by assigning properties to `$`:

```
window.Spark = window.$ = function(selector, context) { ... };

$.ajax = function(method, url) { ... };
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed to know, I can't believe I didn't think of that. I thought the solution had to be a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If you put a function within a function it's local to the outer function, so it's not possible to call it from outside the function.

A function in Javascript is an object like any other, so you can add properties to it, and the property can be a function:

```
var $ = function() { alert("1"); };

$.ajax = function() { alert("2"); };

$(); // shows "1"
$.ajax(); // shows "2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions are first class citizens in JavaScript, i.e. you may treat them like objects are being treated in OOP. It's possible to assign properties to them and those properties may be functions in turn.

So, `$.ajax` is really nothing else then the property `ajax` that's a "member" of the function (object) `$` that happens to be a function.

So long.

Answer (score 0):

Um.... `$.ajax` needs to be a function to be called like that. So either define the 'ajax' function or don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with "not including the brackets," whatever that means. In jQuery, the identifier `$` represents a function object that has several attributes. One of these attributes is `ajax`, which contains a function that performs an AJAX call. Just because you call your own function `$` doesn't mean it automagically gets the functionality of jQuery. If you want `$.ajax` to be a function, you'll need to define it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery, it just happens to have similar syntax.

Comment: @Wolfy87: Yes. That's exactly what I said. You were asking why it doesn't work like jQuery, and that's because it has nothing to do with jQuery and you weren't defining the `ajax` attribute of `$`.